# Chef Upload to Sandbox Fails with 403 (Unauthorized)

Tags: chef-infra

We're calling the Chef API from a .Net application. We have successfully used GET and PUT and POST methods, signing and passing information as required.

However, we have hit a brick wall when attempting to upload files to the Sandbox. And this appears to be an area of Chef that has no documentation.

Firstly we POST to the Sandbox with our file checksum (calculated using MD5). This then returns a signed URL.

Our expectation from this point is that we should be making a PUT to the URL provided and sending our data (I have attempted a GET too, with the same problem). However, whatever we try, we're getting back an error of **403 - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

We've tried:

- Creating a signature as before and sending that with the PUT, no success.
- Not using a signature (relying upon the signature within the URL, no success.
- Attempting to mirror what knife appears to be doing (using -VV), no success.

We would really appreciate any help available on this, pointers to existing documentation and or source code.

TIA

James